# What does "pulling inside" mean?

Tags: meaning

Two bikers, Billy and Wyatt sit by the campfire:

> Wyatt: What's the matter? You zonked? You really zoaned?
>
> Billy: No, I'm just kinda tired, man.
>
> Wyatt: Oh, man, you're **pulling inside**. You're getting a little
> distance tonight.

What does "pulling inside" mean?

Source: Easy Rider (1969)

Comment: Hello Buff.  Please edit to tell us the source of this quote.  And "zoaned" is probably spelled "zoned"

Comment: @JamesK I added **source**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two characters, Billy and Wyatt are both counterculture 1960s people and they are using a *lot* of slang.  In this scene they are also high.

It seems "pulling inside" is a metaphor.  Think of how a snail can pull inside its shell.  So Billy is becoming introspective and inwardly focused, making him seem distant from his friend.

It's not a common expression.